# AppiumDriver get Dimensions size Gives Unknown Error Operation Not Supported in Web View

Tags: appium, appium-android

I'm wondering if anyone has encountered this issue within the last year, (due to the changes applied to io.Appium client within the last few years.) I'm encountering an issue when I attempt to initialize Dimensions inside a method before performing a general swipe in a mobile browser. According to the StackTrace, the error starts when I intialize my Dimensions object, and the error message I'm getting is

```
"org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: operation is unsupported on Android
  (Session info: chrome=68.0.3440.91)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds"
```

I've looked around on discussions on the topic and solution is the one I'm currently using according to Appium Docs when using Web View Context. Is there another factor I'm not considering?

Here is the my method where I initialize my Dimension: size :

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public  void  swipeVertical  (double startPercentage, double finalPercentage, int duration) {
        size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
        int width = (int) (size.width/2);
        int startPoint = (int) (size.getHeight() * startPercentage);
        int endPoint = (int) (size.getHeight() * finalPercentage);
        new TouchAction(driver)
            .press(PointOption.point(width, startPoint))
            .waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(Duration.ofMillis(duration)))
            .moveTo(PointOption.point(width, endPoint))
            .release()
            .perform();
    }
```

And here is the StackTrace:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: operation is unsupported on Android
  (Session info: chrome=68.0.3440.91)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:24:21.231Z'
System info: host: 'LAPTOP-L1BFDSGL', ip: '192.168.174.2', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Capabilities {appiumURL: http://127.0.0.1:5000/wd/hub, browserName: Chrome, databaseEnabled: false, desired: {appiumURL: http://127.0.0.1:5000/wd/hub, browserName: Chrome, deviceName: device1, newCommandTimeout: 4000, noReset: false, platformName: Android, systemPort: 8200, udid: 192.168.174.101:5555}, deviceManufacturer: Genymotion, deviceModel: Samsung, deviceName: 192.168.174.101:5555, deviceScreenSize: 1440x2560, deviceUDID: 192.168.174.101:5555, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: false, networkConnectionEnabled: true, newCommandTimeout: 4000, noReset: false, platform: LINUX, platformName: Android, platformVersion: 6.0, systemPort: 8200, takesScreenshot: true, udid: 192.168.174.101:5555, warnings: {}, webStorageEnabled: false}
Session ID: 4b662163-cef7-439b-bfd1-998dd6f8e5cc
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:80)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:44)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:231)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:46)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteWebDriverOptions$RemoteWindow.getSize(RemoteWebDriver.java:809)
    at AppiumDriverSetUp_Lib.PageObject.swipeVertical(PageObject.java:45)
    at BaseTest.BaseTest.testActivation(BaseTest.java:62)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
... Removed 20 stack frames
```

Driver: AppiumDriver

Browser: Chrome

io.appium java Client: 6.1.0

Context: Web View / Default

(Note: I would like to keep the context in its default if applicable.)

Answer (score 0):

It works fine when driver instance is `AndroidDriver <MobileElement>` and not `AppiumDriver`.

Also you must use `AndroidTouchAction` instead of `TouchAction` class.

Comment: For this instance, the AppiumDriver instances are AndroidDriver. I also fixed the issue by switching context to Native App, the swipe works, even with TouchAction. However, a new problem occurs when attempting to get Dimension sizes when testing in parallel. I'm getting WebDriverException due to a Bootstrap socket crash. (It happens if both devices are attempting to call getWindowSize() at the same time.

Comment: Solve my socket issue by adding UIAutomator2 as my automationName. In DesiredCapabilites.

Comment: It works for me even with other Automation names like Appiun and Espresso.